# Wordpress wp_register_script() error

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am getting following error in my wordpress plugin while registering a js file.

> **PHP Notice**:  `wp_register_script` was called **incorrectly**.
>
> Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts` hooks.
>
> Please see [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) for more information.
>
> (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/wholesale/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3547

Please also

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enq_shipping_js', 1000);
function enq_shipping_js(){
    wp_register_script('customCheckout', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/woocom_shippingByWeight/js/customCheckout.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customCheckout');
}
```

Please help in resolving as calling the `wp_register_script()` function inside the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook also not resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this hook

```
add_action('admin_init', 'enq_shipping_js');
```

or use this functions to your functions.php

```
function enq_shipping_js() {

wp_register_script ( 
          'customCheckout',
          WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/woocom_shippingByWeight/js/customCheckout.js',
          array('jquery'),
          2.0.0, 
          true 
        );

}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enq_shipping_js');
```

enqueue script function

```
function register_all_styles()
{
       wp_enqueue_script( 'customCheckout' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','register_all_styles');
```